Kotlin version incompatibility when building apk with Flutter - Android Studio
I got this error when building my apk:

C:/Users/Hao/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.9.10/dafaf2c27f27c09220cee312df10917d9a5d97ce/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.9.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.

There are some others with binary versions of metadata is 1.8.0 or 1.9.9999, also expected 1.6.0.
I tried solving with ext.kotlin_version in android\build.gradle but nothing changed.
Also trying to downgrade: I got message of too old Kotlin version -> build failed.
Trying to clean/rebuild project: nothing changed.
Trying to clean cache at Users/user/.android but didn't work either.
Also trying to configure Android Studio settings/project structure/plugins.
Rebuild Gradle to sync ./gradlew build, I got: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':google_mobile_ads:test'.

Could not create task ':google_mobile_ads:testProfileUnitTest'.
this and base files have different roots: E:\Projects\project\build\google_mobile_ads and C:\Users\Hao\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\google_mobile_ads-5.2.0\android.

What I have fixed so far since the error appeared:
settings.gradle:
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }()

    includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.1" apply false //downgraded and upgraded
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.10" apply false //changed to 1.6.x / 1.7.x / 1.8.x
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.4.2' apply false //changed to 4.3.15 for another error
}

include ":app"


android\build.gradle:
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.10' //comment in, out
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
//        maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev")
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1")
        classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.2") //changed with the one in settings.gradle
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version") // comment in, out with ext.kotlin_version
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = "../build"
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(":app")
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}


app\build.gradle:
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    // The Flutter Gradle Plugin must be applied after the Android and Kotlin Gradle plugins.
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id "com.google.gms.google-services"
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.5.1')

    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version")
    implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:23.1.0')
    implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:25.1.1')
    implementation('com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.5.0')
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:23.5.0")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:23.5.0")
//    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
//    implementation('com.google.android.gms:play-services-security:18.0.0')
//    implementation('androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0')
//    implementation('androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0')
//    implementation('androidx.annotation:annotation:1.9.1')
//    configurations.all {
//        resolutionStrategy {
//            force "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
//            force "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
//            force "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
//            force "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
//        }
//    }
}
//apply plugins('com.google.gms.google-services')

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file("local.properties")
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty("flutter.versionCode")
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = "1"
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty("flutter.versionName")
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = "1.0"
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.tictactoe_rebuild"
    compileSdk = flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion = flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId = "com.example.tictactoe_rebuild"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdk = 23/*flutter.minSdkVersion*/
        targetSdk = flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode = flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName = flutterVersionName
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source = "../.."
}


I need to fix those for my ads to run.

I've found out that my app can still run ads normally. Yet the error still affects the performance. I'm still hoping for a solution.
